# How should I solve problems like this?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

This is from a math competition for elementary school kids.

x, y, and z are positive integer and they satisfy

[image]

The question ask for the value of -x-y+z

I do not know how to solve this

I can simplify this to

$$\frac{y}{xy+1}+z=\frac{5xy}{7}$$

Then what?

I can go further multiply both sides by $7(xy+1)$

I will get let's see

$$7y+7xyz+7z=5xy(xy+1)$$

Then I do not know what to do

Comment: What is the meaning of $[…]$?

Comment: Those are just brackets. What do you want to know?

Comment: This is the answer i'm waiting for.

Comment: What means "Nilai" ?

Comment: nilai means value

Comment: "*This is from a math competition for elementary school kids.*" - I think OP wants this answered in a way that will also help **elementary school kids** understand how to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP wants this answered in a way *elementary school kids* would understand.

---

If you don't know how to solve it, try making the expression nicer and looking for "clues". I'll be doing that here: I'll assume I do not know number theory, nor how to solve this in any rigorous way. I'll assume we do know that having a factor on one side of the equation implies having it on the other as well.

Since $-x-y+z$ a combination is wanted, we need to either re-write the original problem as that, or find at least one solution for $x,y,z$.

---

When presented with such a problem, I would always first simplify individual terms, as you did:

$$
\frac{y}{xy+1}+z=\frac{5xy}{7}
$$

Then I would get rid of fractions. That is, multiply by denominators:

$$
7y+7z(xy+1)=5xy(xy+1)
$$

Finally I would want to factorize in a nice way. Notice "($xy+1$)" on both sides. Lets try to factor that:

$$
7y=5xy(xy+1)-7z(xy+1) \\
7y=(xy+1)(5xy-7z)
$$

If you've factorized this in a nice way, we should start getting clues.

Notice LHS has a factor $7$. This means RHS must have too. That is:

For $(xy+1)(5xy-7z)$ to have a factor of $7$, either $(xy+1)$ or $(5xy-7z)$ must have a factor of $7$.

Notice the second case  is a combination of a *number* $[5xy]$ and a multiple of $7$ that is $[7z]$. This means that *number* $[5xy]$ must be a multiple of $7$ so that their combination $([5xy]-[7z])$ can be a multiple of $7$, and by that have a factor of $7$.

We now have either $(xy+1)$ or $(5xy)$ must have a factor of $7$.

We can now examine both cases.

First case:

Lets assume the " factor (multiple) of $7$" is the smallest such and keep trying to find smallest solutions.

That is, this gives us $xy+1=7\implies xy=6$. Here, we have $\{x,y\}$ can be $\{1,6\}$ or $\{2,3\}$ to give $6$ when multiplied.

We have: (Use the fact that $xy=6$)

$$\begin{array}{}
7y&=(xy+1)(5xy-7z) \\
7y&=(6+1)(5\cdot 6 -7z) \\
7y&=7(30-7z) \\
y&=30-7z \\
7z&=30-y
\end{array}$$

Notice $y$ is either $1,2,3,6$ and only $2$ works. In that case, we have $\{2,3\}$ so $x=3$.

We now have $z$ as well:

$$
7z=2\cdot14\implies z=4
$$

**And we see that $-x-y+z=-3-2+4=-1$ the answer is $-1$**.

Notice we did not need to try the second case as we've already found a solution here.

If you have started with the second case first, you might have gotten stuck, since that case does not have solutions. In that scenario, if you get "stuck", try the other case - the first case, which in this scenario has a solution.

Comment: wow. Yes. That's how you do it. Now with number theory it's easier. Let me check again

Comment: Good. But much longer. Kids have 1.5 minutes for each problem. WOuld you tell me why hw chu think xy+1 must be 7? How can he conclude that so quickly?

Comment: @user4951 There could be a shorter way, but I do not see it without using claims such as those provided in the other two answers mentioning Euclid's algorithm and modulo. If the kids are in the competition, maybe they can learn some number theory and use that? - I do not remember what was thaught in elementary school and to what level. For the $7$, we know it is a multiple of seven, and I wrote "assume it is the smallest". If it didn't work, you may try the next multiple, or try using $7k$ instead of $7$.

Comment: @user4951 Instead of accepting my answer, maybe you should rewrite the question "how should elementary school kids solve these problems in under 1.5 minutes", since those details are important if that's what kind of solution you want.. Maybe someone can explain basic number theory assuming the reader knowns none and  then provide a short solution using that.

Comment: I see I see. I think I will rewrite. But your answer is one of the best already for elementary kids.

Answer (score 2):

Since $xy + 1$ and $y$ are relatively prime, we must have $xy + 1 = 7$. So $xy = 6$, right hand side is $30/7$ and $z = 4$.

Comment: what makes you think xy+1 and y are relatively prime?

Comment: Apply them to Euclid's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

$x y + 1 = 7 → x y = 6$

Matching fractional parts:  $y ≡ 5 x y \text{ (mod 7)}$

$ 5x ≡ 1 ≡ 15 \text{ (mod 7)} → x=3 → y=2  → z=4$

$-x-y+z = -3-2+4 = -1$

Comment: what makes you think xy+1 =7

Comment: As Hw Chu pointed out, y/(x*y+1) cannot be reduced any furthur.  Denominator must match, thus x*y+1=7